# Botpress UMM send letter by letter with Facebook Messenger

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, chatbot

I'm using **Botpress** to make a simple bot to **Facebook Messenger**, when I use simple String in `AddQuestion` method, all works, but when I change to use UMM is sent to user letter by letter.

My `content.yml`

```
identification_cpf: 'Preciso que você me infome seu CPF (somente números)'
```

My `index.js` with code that uses UMM string definition:

```
  convo.threads['identification'].addQuestion('#identification_cpf', [
    {
      pattern: /(\d+)/i,
      callback: (response) => {
        convo.set('cpf', response.match)
        convo.next()
      }
    }
  ])
```

Result:

[image]

How I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try restructuring your content.yml like this?

```
identification_cpf:
  - text: 'Preciso que você me infome seu CPF (somente números)'
```

do one tab indentation on the second line.